# Autoform and FlowRouter with template level subscriptions within Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema, flow-router

I can't seem to work out how to create a working Autoform "QuickForm" while using FlowRouter. I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in template helper: Error: Footer is not in the window scope
```

This is my Quickform. In this case collection equals a string value of "Footer":

```
{{> quickForm id="formView" type="insert" collection=form.collection }}
```

Perhaps a Quickform, simpleSchema and FlowRouter example will suffice to answer this question.

Comment: Do you have a template named `Footer`?

Comment: Nope, my collection is called Footer though ie:
`Footer = new Mongo.Collection('footer');`

Answer (score 0):

I realised my issue was that the file that created the collection and the template file that rendered the Quickform were in **separate packages**!

I added `api.export("Footer",['client', 'server']);` to the correct package and all worked fine!

Note: I don't yet know if this is the recommend method or if there are security issues with this solution so will not mark this as correct just yet.